# How to access this array

Tags: php, magento-1.9

```
array (
  '_attributes' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Rothco Product API - Variations',
  ),
  'item_variations' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdclass::__set_state(array(
       'item_variation_id' => 2,
       'item_index' => 3146,
       'rothco_item_no' => '10002',
       'upc' => '023063601212',
       'inventory' => 99,
       'created_date' => '2014-11-28 10:06:45.000',
       'weight' => '.4000',
       'image_filename' => '10002-A.jpg',
       'catalog_page_no' => 183,
       'msrp' => '20.9900',
       'map' => '.0000',
       'diameter' => '',
       'price' => '8.100000',
       'case_price' => NULL,
       'case_quantity' => NULL,
       'statuses' => '',
    )),
  ),
)
```

This is my array $list.

I want to access 'item_variations' value from this array,

but if I try `$list['item_variations']`, or `$list->['item_variations']`

it is not working

Comment: Try $list['_attributes']['item_variations'].

Comment: what's the problem ? https://3v4l.org/jLLMR

Comment: Something like this; $list['item_variations'][0]->item_variation_id

Comment: HAve a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657055/how-to-access-the-members-of-this-data-in-php

Comment: @hassan I am not able to access the item_variations with the mentioned ways. If you have any solution please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reach just `item_variations` then

```
echo $list['item_variations'];
```

is sufficient. Things get more tricky if you would like to i.e. get value if `created_date` from your sample data as you got mix of arrays and objects so that require different access:

```
echo $list['item_variations'][0]->created_date;
```

which would output

```
2014-11-28 10:06:45.000
```